# Router-link can't jump to the page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

neither static router nor dynamic router can jump to the page.

html code:

```html
<router-link to="/add_peer">Test</router-link>
<router-link :to="{path:'/add_peer'}">Test</router-link>
```

this is routers
router/index.js:

```
import { createApp,h } from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import {createRouter,createWebHashHistory} from "vue-router";

const routes=[
    {
        path:"/add_peer",
        name:"AddPeer",
        component:()=>import('@/view/add_peer')
    }
];
const routers=createRouter({
    routes,
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
})
const app = createApp({
    render:()=>h(app)
});

app.use(routers)
app.use(VueRouter)
app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a similar codepen.io example? I think the reason it doesnt work is because of your import. I think you should add `.default` behind your import like this.

```
const routes=[
    {
        path:"/add_peer",
        name:"AddPeer",
        component:()=>import('@/view/add_peer').default
    }
];
```

Not sure though but you can try it.